# Australia Hotel/Motel Data

Tags: data-request, csv, sql, australia, excel

I am wondering if there is anyone here that either has 2013-2015 list of hotels in Australia with contact phone numbers and if it had emails that would be a bonus.

I am currently putting an excel spreadsheet together of Melbourne Hotels. But in 3 hours I have only been able to get 46 hotels, and I know that there has to be a quicker and more effective way to do this.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: You might try contacting the government of Australia directly. And/or one of these (very similar) links might help: http://abr.business.gov.au/ http://abr.business.gov.au/LookupToolDownload.aspx -- for best results, try to find whatever code AU uses for "lodging" businesses and see if you can get a data dump. Not a real answer, but hopefully gets you closer to your goal.

Answer (score 2):

DMOZ is a directory and naturally is great for tasks like this. You're going to have to do all of the leg work though: [Search DMOZ for Australia + Hotel](https://www.dmoz.org/search?q=australia+hotel&all=no&t=regional&cat=all)